Feeding a Reverse voltage at the output pin of an isolated DC DC converter
We have designed a Biasing card for an amplifier, In which it consists of a sequencer, a regulator to generate VG and a DC-DC converter along with Hot swap circuit for controlling the VD.
I used THN30-2425 isolated DC-DC converter for biasing the power amplifier to generate 22V (VD) through a 12V input supply and also I have given an option to get direct 22V through a connector which is connected to the output of DC-DC converter.
Now I'm using this biasing circuit for another power amplifier biasing where VG for both the power amplifier is same but only the VD is different, that is 32V(VD) for the power amplifier, I'm planning to connect 32V directly to the VD through the connector which is also connected to output of DC-DC connector.
1.  Without Removing DC-DC Converter from the board Can I off the DC-DC converter by grounding the Remote On/Off pin("which makes the DC-DC converter Off")and give 32V to the connector(J1) which is directly connected to the Output pin of DC-DC converter ?
2.  Will the regulator can hold 32V reverse voltage at the output ?
Here is the schematic for your reference



The datasheet of the THL30-2415WI mentiones an output overvoltage protection implemented using a zener diode, that starts to clamp at 125% of the nominal voltage, which would be 30 V in this module.
So I assume backfeeding it with 32 V might destroy the converter module, even if is is not enabled.
